# the reason for using InverseGamma and LogNormal as prior for covariance matrix or variance

Tags: distributions, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, conjugate-prior

In the Bayesian analysis, sometimes we can see that InverseGamma and LogNormal distributions are used as prior for variance or covariance matrix respectively. What are the logic or explanations of using these two specific distributions?

Comment: I think the wiki article already gives some decent background: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_linear_regression